# Using scheme to build a tree and print node of the in_order traversal

Tags: tree, scheme, binary-tree, racket, mit-scheme

I understand the algorithm but cannot get the code work using scheme.
I'm building a binary search tree. A node is a pair of (key value).
in java, the code works fine:

```
public void inOrder(BinaryNode n) {
    if (n != null) {
        inOrder(n.left);
        System.out.println(n.value);
        inOrder(n.right);
    }
}
```

in scheme, my starting code as follows:

```
(define empty ())

(define empty? null?)

(define (node_key tn) (list-ref tn 0))

(define (node_val tn) (list-ref tn 1))

(define (node_left tn) (list-ref tn 2))

(define (node_right tn) (list-ref tn 3))

(define (tree-node key value left right) (list key value left right))

(define (get-key tn) (node_key tn))

(define (get-val tn) (node_val tn))

(define (get-left tn) (node_left tn))

(define (get-right tn) (node_right tn))

(define (get-pair tn) (list (get-key tn) (get-val tn)))

(define (atom? tn) (and (empty? (get-left tn)) (empty? (get-right tn))))

(define (printInOrder  t)
  (if (not (empty? t))       
      (begin
        (printInOrder (get-left t))
        (get-pair t)
        (printInOrder (get-right t))
        )
      )
  )
```

However, if we test the printInOrder:

```
(define a (tree-node 3 30 empty empty))

(define b (tree-node 1 10 empty empty))

(define c (tree-node 2 20 b a))

(printInOrder  c)
```

it should print:

```
1 10
2 20
3 30
```

but it doesn't work, print out nothing.

Could anyone help with this matter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written is roughly equivalent to:

```
public void inOrder(BinaryNode n) {
    if (n != null) {
        preOrder(n.left);
        n.value;
        preOrder(n.left);
    }
}
```

(... except that Java will probably treat the naked *n.value* as a syntax error since isn't being used for anything interesting.)

Expressions do not automatically print out their values unless their values reach the toplevel.  Otherwise, you've got to print the values explicitly.  You can use *display* and *newline* to get the effect of *System.out.println*.  If you're using Racket, you've also got [printf](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._printf%29%29) to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I've corrected my code as follows and it works!

(define (display-inorder t)

  (if (not (empty? t))

      (begin

        (display-inorder (get-left t))

        (display (get-pair t))

        (display-inorder (get-right t))

      )
  )
)

Answer (score 0):

Alan, for a java coder, you're littering your top level environment with many functions.  Consider a node object like this:

```
    (define make-node
      (lambda (key value)
        (let ((left '()) (right '()))
          (lambda (m)
            (cond
              ((eq? m 'key) key)
              ((eq? m 'value) value)
              ((eq? m 'left) left)
              ((eq? m 'right) right)
              ((eq? m 'set-left) (lambda (x) (set! left x)))
              ((eq? m 'set-right) (lambda (x) (set! right x)))
              (else (error "Error (make-node): unknown op " m)) )))))
```

You'd need a little more than this to make a fully-fledged tree, of course; you'd want a list object with at least an insert method (doing it manually, as you are doing, means you could accidentally put the wrong node into "left" or "right" at any point in the tree).  I'd also add a list-in-order method to the tree object, returning a list of key->value pairs, and then you could do anything with the list (including display it).

I'm not saying that's the best way to build the tree, but it's cleaner.

Comment: Not the right time to distract with issues on style!  :)  Depending on what part of whatever curriculum he or she is working with (such as SICP), it might not quite be the right timing yet: they might not have learned about treating closures as objects.  If he or she's using a professional implementation, structures or records should be the go-to for representing the nodes, not list-representation.  I'm assuming this is homework so there are some artificial constraints here.

Comment: Hi, thank you guys! I will experiment this. Truly seems much cleaner.
Like what Dyoo said, it is homework so that some functions are fixed.
However, we can still make our own structure without changing the structure of the basic things (eg. node with key-value, procedure-args, params, etc)
 Moreover, I’m totally new to scheme and I might be seeking for you professionals’ help during my scheme learning.
I appreciate you all very much and many thanks again.

Comment: Enjoy Scheme.  It's a beautiful language.